# Rotate image from front view to left view with 3D effect

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am using the code below to rotate the image, but I can only achieve to rotate the image from front view to bottom view. I want to rotate the image from front view to left view. How can I achieve this?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.thumb {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.thumb a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("https://i.imgur.com/9NVqw8Q.jpg");
  background-size: 0, cover;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.thumb:hover a {
  transform: rotateX(80deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.thumb a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  background: inherit;
  background-size: cover, cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.thumb a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.15;
  transform: rotateX(95deg) translateZ(-80px) scale(0.75);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.thumb:hover a:before {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(-60px) scale(0.85);
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Modify [`rotateX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotateX) to [`rotateY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotatey) since left view makes use of the vertical axis.
2. Modify the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) to `left` as we are transforming with the left side as the rotating point.
3. Apply the similar changes to the pseudo elements for the 3D look as mentioned by @kaiido. I have commented the changes made.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.thumb {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin: 100px; /* For snippet spacing */
}

.thumb a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("https://i.imgur.com/9NVqw8Q.jpg");
  background-size: 0, cover;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.thumb:hover a {
  transform: rotateY(45deg); /* 1 - From rotateX */
  transform-origin: left; /* 2 - From bottom */
}

.thumb a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 36px; /* Interchanged width and height because horizontal transformation is now vertical transformation */ 
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  background-size: cover, cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  transform: rotateY(90deg); /* 1 - From rotateX */
  transform-origin: left; /* 2 - From bottom */
}

.thumb a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.15;
  transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(-40px) scale(0.75); /* 3 - From rotateX */
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.thumb:hover a:before {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: rotateY(0) translateZ(-60px) scale(0.85); /* 3 - From rotateX */
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you inlcude the side wrap so it look more like 3d? Just like on my previous code, you can see the wrap at the bottom of the iimage. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Okay then make use of `transform-origin: center;`

Comment: @PhilGreene do the same changes with the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements https://jsfiddle.net/cs1r92kn/

Comment: Sorry I forgot the `::before`'s `transform-origin: bottom` -> `left;` in my fiddle, I personnaly even feel `bottom left` looks better btw. https://jsfiddle.net/v95fjokz/

Answer (score 1):

@manoj-kumar is right.
make use of `rotateX` to `rotateY`

also you have to set `transform-origin` and `position` for the `:after` to make it wrap on left

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hellooutlook/6sagLtpk/2/

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.thumb {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.thumb a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("https://i.imgur.com/9NVqw8Q.jpg");
  background-size: 0, cover;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.thumb:hover a {
  transform: rotateY(60deg);
  /* From rotateX */
  transform-origin: left;
  /* From bottom */
}

.thumb a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  background-size: cover, cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  transform: rotateY(110deg);
  transform-origin: left;
  /* extra */
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.thumb a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.15;
  transform: rotateX(15deg) translateZ(-40px) scale(0.75);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.thumb:hover a:before {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(-60px) scale(0.85);
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```